# c# how to store two 4 bit numbers into one byte

Tags: c#

So I have two 4 `bits` number (between 0 and 15):

```
int a = 1;
int b = 15;
```

And I want to store them into 1 `byte`.

This is what I have try:

```
byte[] bytesA = BitConverter.GetBytes(a);
byte[] bytesB = BitConverter.GetBytes(b);
byte a = bytesA[0];
byte b = bytesB[1];
```

Comment: Which value should the `byte` variable have with the given values `1` and `15`?

Comment: [Bitwise and shift operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators)

Comment: 2 bits numbers that stored into 1 byte

Comment: user @Steve: what operation i need to use at the link you provide?

Comment: _int result = (a << 4) + b;_

Comment: `byte ab = (a << 4) | b;` to get the values out: `GetB() => (byte)(ab & 0xF);`, `GetA() => (byte)((ab >> 4) & 0xF);`

Comment: @Space why don't you post that as answer?

Comment: @Space If you want to assign the result to a byte (ab) you need a cast

Comment: @Steve my bad forgot to write that

Answer (score 0):

Sins a byte is 8 bits and you have 2 4 bit values, you will need to [shift](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators) one of the values to occupy the high 4 bits of the resulting byte, like so:

```
byte ab = (byte)((a << 4) | (b & 0xF));
```

To get `a` out of `ab`:

```
byte a = (byte)((ab >> 4) & 0xF);
```

To get `b` out of `ab`:

```
byte b = (byte)(ab & 0xF);
```